# Python 3.5 / Pastebin "Bad API request, invalid api_option"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pastebin

I'm working on a twitch irc bot and one of the components I wanted to have available was the ability for the bot to save quotes to a pastebin paste on close, and then retrieve the same quotes on start up.

I've started with the saving part, and have hit a road block where I can't seem to get a valid post, and I can't figure out a method.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

# --------------------------------------------- Pastebin Requisites --------------------------------------------------

pastebin_key = 'my pastebin key'  # developer api key, required. GET: http://pastebin.com/api
pastebin_password = 'password'  # password for pastebin_username
pastebin_postexp = 'N'  # N = never expire
pastebin_private = 0  # 0 = Public 1 = unlisted 2 = Private
pastebin_url = 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'
pastebin_username = 'username'  # user corresponding with key


# --------------------------------------------- Value clean up --------------------------------------------------

pastebin_password = urllib.parse.quote(pastebin_password, safe='/')
pastebin_username = urllib.parse.quote(pastebin_username, safe='/')

# --------------------------------------------- Pastebin Functions --------------------------------------------------

def post(title, content):  # used for posting a new paste
    pastebin_vars = {'api_option': 'paste', 'api_user_key':     pastebin_username, 'api_paste_private': pastebin_private,
                 'api_paste_name': title, 'api_paste_expire_date': pastebin_postexp,  'api_dev_key': pastebin_key,
                 'api_user_password': pastebin_password, 'api_paste_code': content}
    try:
        str_to_paste = ', '.join("{!s}={!r}".format(key, val) for (key, val) in pastebin_vars.items())  # dict to str :D
        str_to_paste = str_to_paste.replace(":", "")  # remove :
        str_to_paste = str_to_paste.replace("'", "")  # remove '
        str_to_paste = str_to_paste.replace(")", "")  # remove )
        str_to_paste = str_to_paste.replace(", ", "&")  # replace dividers with &
        urllib.request.urlopen(pastebin_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(pastebin_vars)).read()
        print('did that work?')
    except:
        print("post submit failed :(")
        print(pastebin_url + "?" + str_to_paste)  # print the output for test

 post("test", "stuff")
```

I'm open to importing more libraries and stuff, not really sure what I'm doing wrong after working on this for two days straight :S

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `try`/`except` block is throwing away the actual error. You should almost never use a "bare" `except` clause without capturing or re-raising the original exception. See [this article](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/) for a full explanation.

Once you remove the `try`/`except`, and you will see the underlying error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "paste.py", line 42, in post
    urllib.request.urlopen(pastebin_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(pastebin_vars)).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 461, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1112, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

This means you're trying to pass a unicode string into a function that's expecting bytes. When you do I/O (like reading/writing files on disk, or sending/receiving data over HTTP) you typically need to encode any unicode strings as bytes. See [this presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) for a good explanation of unicode vs. bytes and when you need to encode and decode.

Next, this line:

```
urllib.request.urlopen(pastebin_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(pastebin_vars)).read()
```

Is throwing away the response, so you have no way of knowing the result of your API call. Assign this to a variable or return it from your function so you can then inspect the value. It will either be a URL to the paste, or an error message from the API.

Next, I think your code is sending a lot of unnecessary parameters to the API and your `str_to_paste` statements aren't necessary.

I was able to make a paste using the following, much simpler, code:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

PASTEBIN_KEY = 'my-api-key' # developer api key, required. GET: http://pastebin.com/api
PASTEBIN_URL = 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'

def post(title, content):  # used for posting a new paste
    pastebin_vars = dict(
        api_option='paste',
        api_dev_key=PASTEBIN_KEY,
        api_paste_name=title,
        api_paste_code=content,
    )
    return urllib.request.urlopen(PASTEBIN_URL, urllib.parse.urlencode(pastebin_vars).encode('utf8')).read()
```

Here it is in use:

```
>>> post("test", "hello\nworld.")
b'http://pastebin.com/v8jCkHDB'
```

Comment: **this answer is encompassing it's going to take time for me to truly understand it, thank you**

Comment: Oh one further question, how do I see the server response from sending the post() ?

Comment: @Cyrohzin No problem! Just assign it to a variable. `url = post("test", "hello\nworld.")`

Comment: I tried using this code with just adding my dev key to it and left everything else as is and i get am getting 'post not defined' error. Any ideas?  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'post' is not defined

Comment: @Syperus `post` is the name of the function I defined, how are you calling that function? You'll need to post more of your code.

Comment: @StevenKryskalla my code looks just like your's. I was testing out your code and the only thing imodified was the dev key. I put in my own person dev key and left everything else the same then jumped into python shell using python3 command. From there i tried to use post("Testing", "Test worked") and i just keep getting error saying post is not defined even though it's def post. Can't post all the code cause i ran out of characters. But like i said i just c/p your code and ran python3 then post("Testing", "Test worked"). Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Syperus try pasting your code & interpreter output in a pastebin and I can take a look. I usually use https://gist.github.com/.

Comment: @Syperus What filename did you use to save the python code? How are you entering the python3 interpreter? After you enter the python interpreter, you need to import the module. E.g. if you named it `pastebin.py`, you would run `from pastebin import post`. You could also run `python3 -i pastebin.py` to load an interpreter with the module already loaded. See the official tutorial here for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @StevenKryskalla well son of a gun. That was my problem not importing. Working now! Thanks for your help. Will give you credit on this project and send you the link to the project when its fully up and running.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

PASTEBIN_KEY = 'xxx'
PASTEBIN_URL = 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php'
PASTEBIN_LOGIN_URL = 'https://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php'
PASTEBIN_LOGIN = 'my_login_name'
PASTEBIN_PWD = 'yyy'

def pastebin_post(title, content):
    login_params = dict(
        api_dev_key=PASTEBIN_KEY,
        api_user_name=PASTEBIN_LOGIN,
        api_user_password=PASTEBIN_PWD
    )

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_params).encode("utf-8")
    req = urllib.request.Request(PASTEBIN_LOGIN_URL, data)

    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
        pastebin_vars = dict(
            api_option='paste',
            api_dev_key=PASTEBIN_KEY,
            api_user_key=response.read(),
            api_paste_name=title,
            api_paste_code=content,
            api_paste_private=2,
        )
        return urllib.request.urlopen(PASTEBIN_URL, urllib.parse.urlencode(pastebin_vars).encode('utf8')).read()

rv = pastebin_post("This is my title", "These are the contents I'm posting")
print(rv)
```

Combining two different answers above gave me this working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about pastebin until now. I read their api and tried it for the first time, and it worked perfectly fine.

Here's what I did:

- I logged in to fetch the `api_user_key`.
- Included that in the posting along with `api_dev_key`.
- Checked the website, and the post was there.

Here's the code:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request


def post(url, params):
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_params).encode("utf-8")
    req = urllib.request.Request(login_url, data)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
       return response.read()


# Logging in to fetch api_user_key
login_url = "http://pastebin.com/api/api_login.php"
login_params = {"api_dev_key": "<the dev key they gave you",
                "api_user_name": "<username goes here>",
                "api_user_password": "<password goes here>"}
api_user_key = post(login_url, login_params)


# Posting some random text
post_url = "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"
post_params = {"api_dev_key": "<the dev key they gave you",
               "api_option": "paste",
               "api_paste_code": "<head>Testing</head>",
               "api_paste_private": "0",
               "api_paste_name": "testing.html",
               "api_paste_expire_date": "10M",
               "api_paste_format": "html5",
               "api_user_key": api_user_key}
response = post(post_url, post_params)
```

Only the first three parameters are needed for posting something, the rest are optional.

Answer (score 0):

fwy the API doesn't seem to accept http requests as of writing this, so make sure to have the urls in the format of `https://pas...`